# Creare a custom action for an existing button in a webview

Tags: iphone

I'm displaying an URL on a webview, and on that page there is a button. How can I customize the action that occurs when that button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You controller has to respond to `<UIWebViewDelegate>`.

Then, override this method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) 
    {
        NSURL *URL = [request URL]; 
        if ([[URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"http://give.it.a.custom.url.to.identify.this.action"].length > 0)   
         {
             // your custom action here
         }

        return NO;
    }   
    return YES;   
}
```

Don't forget the  `[youWebView setDelegate:self];`.